Are there any reported/documented cases of unintended transport of birds within planes (freight compartment, cargo planes)
I am currently working on the unintentional transport of birds and have come across the possibility that small birds, e.g. sparrows, could be unintentionally transported by aircraft. This could be due to their life in close proximity to humans (including airports), their small size and the fact that House Sparrows in particular regularly fly inside buildings.
I haven't found any reports of this yet, but there have been sightings of sparrows at remote airstrips, far from road access. Are there any documented cases? I think it's unlikely on international passenger flights, but perhaps more likely on less-controlled domestic flights, military or civilian cargo flights.
Many thanks.

Of course I'm sure you are well aware that snakes have been unintentionally transported in landing gear bays --

I'd be a little doubtful if there is any report to be made in most cases.  Okay, some sparrow flew inside the C-17 shortly before they closed it up. Probably spent the flight sitting on top of the highest piece of cargo, and flew away at some point after the cargo door opened and everything was unloaded. So? I rather doubt that military loadmasters have an "inadvertent bird transport report" form that they might fill out - although there is at least one reference to a Hazardous Chicken Road Crossing Report.

Yes, there are. For instance, see this report from The Aviation Herald:

An Air India Express Boeing 737-800, [...], was enroute at FL370 over the Arabian Sea when a live bird was noticed in the cockpit.
India's DGCA reported the bird was noticed when the glove department at the first officer's side was opened. An investigation has been opened, it appears a ground handling lapse had occurred at the remote station.

